# JavaFx BST visualisation nodes overlapping problem

Tags: java, recursion, javafx, binary-search-tree

I am creating an app that will visually represent BST in JavaFx. Problem is that node's right branch overlaps with another node's left branch. As shown in the picture.
Should I somehow in every call adjust the length of the line or is there any other solution?

[image]

[image]

Code used to draw BST recursively:

```
 public void drawNodeRecursive(int x1, int y1, int x, int y, Node node) {

        Line line = new Line(x1, y1 + 5, x, y);
        gp.getChildren().add(line);
        Circle circle = new Circle(x, y, 30, Paint.valueOf("black"));
        gp.getChildren().add(circle);
        Text txt = new Text(x - 3, y + 3, String.valueOf(node.getVrednost()));
        txt.setFill(Color.WHITE);

        gp.getChildren().add(txt);
        if (node.getLevi() != null) {
            drawNodeRecursive(x, y, x - (120), y + 120, node.getLevi());
        }
        if (node.getDesni() != null) {
            drawNodeRecursive(x, y, x + (120), y + 120, node.getDesni());
        }
    }
```

Comment: It depends on how you want to display it, but each level has `2**n` nodes, so you'll need to make space for all of them naively as done [here](https://github.com/ggorlen/prettybt/blob/28455062c2116a657336d4d4398bfe8c67e934a3/js/pbt.js#L38), or be smart about filling in missing gaps for sparse trees.

Comment: You would need to compute the width the the tree to know how to place the node so that they do not overlap.

Comment: The horizontal distance between nodes needs to decrease with each row. Since in the worst case every node has two child nodes, decreasing it by a factor of 2 in each row will always be sufficient.

Comment: You could use a library such as [graphviz](https://github.com/nidi3/graphviz-java) or [yfiles](https://www.yworks.com/yfiles-overview) to draw the tree.  Probably not necessary for a bst, but useful for more complex trees if you also need to draw them.